# Debug Assertion Error as soon as I take the input. Something wrong with "delete"?

Tags: debugging, runtime-error

I am having debug assertion error as soon as I input two elements. The program was giving me access reading or sometimes writing violation error after taking 7-8 entries but after I deleted the dynamic array, it is showing debug assertion failed after taking first two inputs and breaks down. Any idea for how to solve it? I am copying only my air class here. I have similar Fire, earth and water classes too.

The error is BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID (pHead->nBlockUse)
Someone else too asked this question but i can't figure out My program errors. Kindly help would be appreciated.

```
#ifndef AIR_H
#define AIR_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "element.h"
using namespace std;

class Air :public Element
{
public:
    string air;
    string Elements [2];
    int i;
    string *elements; 

public:
    Air(string n): Element (n)
    {
        air = n;
        i=-1;
        elements = new string[2];
    }


void alreadyExists (string a)
    {
        int lineCount = 0;
        ifstream read;
        read.open ("Air.txt", ios::in | ios::app);
        while(!read.eof())
            {
                string x;
                read>>x;
                lineCount++;

            }

            lineCount--;
            read.close();
            read.open("Air.txt", ios::in|ios::app);
            for(int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)
            {
                read>>elements[i];
            }
            bool Found = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
                if(a == elements[i]) 
                {
                    Found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!Found) 
            {
                write2file (a);

            }
    }


void write2file (string air)
{
    ofstream write;
    write.open ("Air.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
    {
        write<<air<<endl;

    }

}


     void DisplayA ()
     {
         /*for(int i=0; i<2; i++)//( to read through the arrays )
         {
             cout<<Elements[i]<<endl;
         }*/
         ifstream read ("Air.txt", ios::in|ios::app);

         int i=0;
         while (read >> Elements[i])
                 {
                     cout<<Elements[i]<<endl;
                 }

     }

     Air operator+(Air & air) 
    {                                         
        Air newElement ("NULL");        
        if (this->air == "Air"||this->air=="air"&& air.air == "Air"||air.air=="air")
        {
            newElement.air = "Pressure";
            cout<<"Yay!! You've made: "<<newElement.air<<endl;
            alreadyExists (newElement.air);

            //PushA (newElement.air);
            //write2file (newElement.air);
            return newElement;
        }

        else if ((this->air == "Air"||this->air == "air") && (air.air == "Pressure"||air.air=="pressure"))/* || ((this->air == "Pressure"||this->air=="pressure") && ( air.air == "Air"||air.air=="air")))*/
        {
            newElement.air = "Atmosphere";
            cout<<"Wuhooo!! You've made: "<<newElement.air<<endl;
            alreadyExists (newElement.air);
            //PushA (newElement.air);
            //write2file (newElement.air);
            return newElement;
        }

        else return newElement;

     }//pressure, atmosphere

    ~ Air ()
    {
        delete []elements;
    }

};
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID (pHead->nBlockUse)
```

Assertion means a corrupt heap at deleting/clearing.

As far as I see, you missed the virtual deconstructor of Element.
Try something like:

```
virtual ~Element() {}
```

in class Element.
And please post also the Element class.

Good luck!